# Почему в activity_mail.xml не отображается дизайн андроида

Tags: android-studio

Почему не отображается дизайн андроида?

У меня есть SDK, все сделал правильно но не отображается почему-то помогите пожалуйста.

[image]

Comment: Покажите `build.gradle`. У вас он не засинкался, засим не подключены нужные библиотеки. Скорее всего вам надо удалить пока что оттуда лишние тестовые зависимости

Comment: а как показать скажите

Comment: Через [правку вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/739991/edit) вы можете добавить содержимое файлов в виде текста